# When do we have $C(G) \otimes C(G) =C(G\times G)?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be a group and $C(G)$ be the set of complex valued functions on $G$.

Can someone please let me know why $C(G) \otimes C(G)$ is only dense in $C(G\times G)$ and the two are different if $G$ is not a finite group.

The idea comes from defining a Hopf algebra structure on $C(G)$ and we need to define the co-multiplication $\Delta: C(G) \to C(G) \otimes C(G) $!

Thanks!

Comment: Density means nothing unless p your group has a topology

Comment: @ashwin, if you require what to be homomorphisms?

Comment: Can you see why the two are different if the group is the real line?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks! Can you please explain more? No I cannot see it. What happens if $G$ is real line?

Comment: I suggest you consider several examples of functions on $G\times G$ when $G=\mathbb R$ and try to see if they belong to the subspace or not. In other words: consider examples. How else do you think one sees things?!

Comment: To expand on Mariano's recommendation of how to "see" this: Why can't every function $f: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb C$ be decomposed as $f(x,y) = \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n g_i(x)h_i(y)$ for some $g_i, h_i: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$? You should see that a function of the form $g(x)h(y)$ is very special indeed.